# How do you create a view that is specific to an object you create with the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm doing a hobby project a bug tracker.
And i want to be able to create a project with my database that I will be able to click on and then get a view where i can log information about the project and be able to make tickets for the project.

I have made two models, a project model then a ticket model  I have created a one to many relationship between them. And i also made two controllers one for project and one for ticket.
Both project and ticket can perform CRUD operations. The only problem is that I do not really know how to get them put together in the project, to get details about an individual project.
I have a relationship between the models. But how do I get a view that is specific to my project?

**My models**

```
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Project_Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }

public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int Ticket_Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TicketName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TicketDescription { get; set; }

        public DateTime TicketCreated { get; set; }

        public string TicketPriority { get; set; }

        public string TicketType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Project")]
        public int Project_Id { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a code for some like your situation, it could help you

**Models**

```
  public class Procedure_s 
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int PrId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PrName { get; set; }
    public string PrDescribe { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
    public DateTime PrStartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
    public DateTime PrEndDate { get; set; }
    public string PrNote { get; set; }

    // foreign Keys
    public int PtyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PtyId")]
    public virtual ProceType ProceType { get; set; }

}

 public class ProceType
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int PtyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PtyName { get; set; }
    public string PtyNote { get; set; }

    //connected tables 
    public virtual IList<Procedure_s> Procedure_s { get; set; }
```

**Controller**:
Details Method

```
       // GET: ProceTypes/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var proceType = await _context.ProceType
            .Include(p => p.Procedure_s)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PtyId == id);
        if (proceType == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(proceType);
    }
```

**View**:
Details page

```
@model DirManageSys.Models.TaskSys.ProceType

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>ProceType</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PtyName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PtyName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PtyNote)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PtyNote)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.PtyId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<table id="tblData" class="table table-hover table-bordered text-black-50" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedure_s[0].PrName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedure_s[0].PrStartDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedure_s[0].PrEndDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedure_s[0].PrDescribe)
            </th>
            
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedure_s[0].PrNote)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedure_s[0].ProceType)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Procedure_s)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrStartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrEndDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrDescribe)
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrNote)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProceType.PtyName)
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PrId">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.PrId">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.PrId">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this code show table of procedures on the Details page of proce type,
which View the

> one-to-many relationship of two models

on razor page by showing information of first model and table of the second model

Comment: Thank you ! I Will walk through it :), where do you place your method in which controller ?

Comment: you are Welcome, this method in ProceType controller , note that it could be for details or for index too